# Is there a way to speed up looping over numpy.where?

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing

Imagine you have a segmentation map, where each object is identified by a unique index, e.g. looking similar to this:

[image]

For each object, I would like to save which pixels it covers, but I could only come up with the standard `for` loop so far. Unfortunately, for larger images with thousands of individual objects, this turns out to be very slow--for my real data at least. Can I somehow speed things up?

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.draw import random_shapes


# please ignore that this does not always produce 20 objects each with a
# unique color. it is simply a quick way to produce data that is similar to
# my problem that can also be visualized.
segmap, labels = random_shapes(
    (100, 100), 20, min_size=6, max_size=20, multichannel=False,
    intensity_range=(0, 20), num_trials=100,
)
segmap = np.ma.masked_where(segmap == 255, segmap)

object_idxs = np.unique(segmap)[:-1]
objects = np.empty(object_idxs.size, dtype=[('idx', 'i4'), ('pixels', 'O')])

# important bit here:

# this I can vectorize
objects['idx'] = object_idxs
# but this I cannot. and it takes forever.
for i in range(object_idxs.size):
    objects[i]['pixels'] = np.where(segmap == i)

# just plotting here
fig, ax = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True)
image = ax.imshow(
    segmap, cmap='tab20', norm=mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=20)
)
fig.colorbar(image)
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `np.where` in a loop is not efficient algorithmically since the *time complexity* is `O(s n m)` where `s = object_idxs.size` and `n, m = segmap.shape`. This operation can be done in `O(n m)`.

One solution using Numpy is to first select all the object pixel locations, then sort them based on their associated object in `segmap`, and finally split them based on the number of objects. Here is the code:

```py
background = np.max(segmap)
mask = segmap != background
objects = segmap[mask]
uniqueObjects, counts = np.unique(objects, return_counts=True)
ordering = np.argsort(objects)
i, j = np.where(mask)
indices = np.vstack([i[ordering], j[ordering]])
indicesPerObject = np.split(indices, counts.cumsum()[:-1], axis=1)

objects = np.empty(uniqueObjects.size, dtype=[('idx', 'i4'), ('pixels', 'O')])
objects['idx'] = uniqueObjects
for i in range(uniqueObjects.size):
    # Use `tuple(...)` to get the exact same type as the initial code here
    objects[i]['pixels'] = tuple(indicesPerObject[i])
# In case the conversion to tuple is not required, the loop can also be accelerated:
# objects['pixels'] = indicesPerObject
```

Comment: Oh wow, that's pretty nifty! Maybe stupid question, but shouldn't I be able to drop the `for` loop with this as well now and simply do `objects['pixels'] = indicesPerObject`?

Comment: Indeed, it should work. By the way, note that this is certainly not done in "parallel". It is said to be "vectorized". Thank you for the edit. Parallelism can occur due to SIMD instruction being used (and IPC too like in all programs), "parallel" often refers to the use of multiple thread and AFAIK Numpy does not use multiple threads internally (at least not in the default implementation). Some functions like matrix multiplication use external libraries like BLAS which can use multiple threads though.

Comment: Sorry, I meant vectorization. Thanks for the clarification! I'm not very sure on the exact definition of these terms.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would like to see where any object is located. So if we start with one matrix (that is, all shapes are in one array, where empty spaces are zeros and object one consists of 1s, object 2 of 2s etc.) then You can create a mask, showing which pixels (or values in a matrix) are non-zero like this:

`my_array != 0`

Comment: Hi, thanks. I'm not sure what you mean. Can you elaborate?

Comment: So, say if object 4 consists of 4s in a matrix of zeros, You would find it by using `my_array == 4` - this will result in a True / False mask for object 4.
If you want to find any object, you can just use the code != 0 to see any matrix values (or pixels in your case) to see where the objects are

Comment: I see. That's what `segmap == i` does. But this only gives me the mask, whereas I want to know the pixel idices, which is what `np.where` does.

Comment: Ok, then just use `np.where` on the entire matrix and you will get your result

Comment: That's what I'm doing, but it's very slow.

Comment: What I mean is: don't iterate over the matrix, just do `np.where(antire_array == 1)` and You will get indexes. For me it works super fast - remember to avoid iteration over an `np.array`

Comment: I'm sorry, I think we are missunderstanding each other. I'm not iterating over the matrix, I'm iterating over the objects, and I have to call `np.where` for each of them.