# Numpy Image processing : Optimize pixel value extraction

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, optimization, vectorization

I'm working on image segmentation and classification, but got to a point where I really have to optimize this whole thing.

Basically, I have :

1. `feature_array`  multiple images stacked into one (x, y, 7)array (float).
2. `segments_array`   a single band image representing image segments, computed with [scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_segmentations.html#compact-watershed-segmentation-of-gradient-images).

My goal is to extract the pixels of `feature_array`, for each image segment.
Example of inputs :

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.segmentation import quickshift

np.random.seed(1224)
A = np.random.randint(1,100,(100,100,7))
B = quickshift(A[:,:,:3])
B
> array([[ 0,  0,  0, ...,  2,  2,  2],
       [ 0,  0,  0, ...,  2,  2,  2],
       [ 0,  0,  0, ...,  2,  2,  2],
       ...,
       [15, 15, 15, ..., 16, 16, 16],
       [15, 15, 15, ..., 16, 16, 16],
       [15, 15, 15, ..., 16, 16, 16]], dtype=int64)
```

my code is as follows:

````
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def get_pixels_from_id(seg_id):
    # Extracts the pixels returns an array of shape (number of bands, number of segment pixels)
    mask = segments_array == seg_id
    return feature_array[mask].transpose()

#Getting unique segments ids
unique_seg = np.unique(segments_array)  

# Storing data in pd.DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(segments, columns=['Ids'])
# Extracting pixels for each segment
df['Pixels'] = df['Ids'].map(get_pixels_from_id)

# Gives the values (reflectance) of each pixel of ```feature_array``` present in segment of Id 1.
df['Pixels'][1] 

>array([[44, 59, 30, 44, 23, 97,  6, 33, 96, 42, 91, 84, 74, 35, 43, 74,
        64, 27, 31, 60, 59, 68, 34, 81, 11, 64, 37, 25, 47, 16, 68, 64,
        97, 65, 37, 61, 74, 39, 76, 14, 79, 81, 92, 13, 35, 24, 61, 98,
        59, 10, 85, 60, 82, 12, 45, 10, 34, 93, 65, 75, 77, 63, 48,  2,
        72, 39, 18, 66, 57, 86, 40, 52, 43, 26, 76, 17, 95, 40,  2, 26,
         3, 64, 56,  9, 10, 45, 99, 78, 85, 35, 88, 47, 55, 94, 75, 27,
        33, 48, 28, 56, 71, 43, 60,  1, 70, 72, 40, 52,  4, 71, 77, 16,
        25, 99, 25, 45], ...)
````

Now, I need to apply this to very large images, and this program takes forever.
I've read a bit about vectorisation, but I'm not sure i'm doing it correctly :

```
vect_fun = np.vectorize(get_pixels_from_id)
vect_fun(df['Ids'].values)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Plus, some people commented on other posts (different topics) that it may not improve execution time.

I know there is parallelization, and that would be my last resort. But is there anyway to improve my code ?

Thank you !

Comment: @CrisLuengo Edited the post, hopefully it's clearer, thanks for reading.

Comment: which part of the code exactly is the slow part? please measure timings or use a profiler -- `np.vectorize` doesn't do what you think. don't use it here, it does nothing in this situation. -- since you do image processing, perhaps don't store coordinates in a dataframe. present the problem. then people can discuss approaches.

Comment: It looks like you want to do the same thing as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71240258/is-there-a-way-to-speed-up-looping-over-numpy-where/71241886 , isn't it?

Comment: @JérômeRichard, Thank you, it's very similar, but i'd like to extract values from a multiband array instead of pixel ids, I just reposted a simplified version of my question.